# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error on android 13 using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my project to develop android application. I got the error below when i udate the android:targetSdkVersion from 30 to 33.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install
> output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse
> during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl417360231.tmp/base.apk (at
> Binary XML file line #50): crc64bf328679f9896e0c.MyFirebaseIIDService:
> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value
> for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
>
> at
> Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String
> output, String packageName) in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:line
> 357    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> AndroidDeviceExtensions.d__12.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line
> 208
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> AndroidDeviceExtensions.d__12.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line
> 225
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.d__106.MoveNext() in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line
> 351
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.d__106.MoveNext() in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line
> 368
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.d__100.MoveNext() in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line
> 216    0

My AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="com.myapplication.app" android:versionName="2.6.1" android:versionCode="16">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:label="FieldDirect" android:largeHeap="true" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/icon_transparent" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/brown" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="MyKey" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.myapplication.app.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please anyone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
> installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl417360231.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
> file line #50): crc64bf328679f9896e0c.MyFirebaseIIDService: Targeting
> S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for
> android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

From document [Safer component exporting](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12),we could find that

> If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains activities,
> services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must
> explicitly declare the `android:exported` attribute for these app
> components.

and we can notice the warning as follows:

> Warning: If an activity, service, or broadcast receiver uses intent
> filters and doesn't have an explicitly-declared value for
> `android:exported`, your app can't be installed on a device that runs
> Android 12 or higher.

From the error log you posted above, you can recheck if you have added `android:exported` to `MyFirebaseIIDService.cs`

For example:

```
[Service(Exported=true, Name="com.xamarin.example.DemoService")]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : Service
{
    
}
```

Comment: It is working fine now. Thank you for your help Jessie Zhang - MSFT